How to export data into custom excel template? General process
Generally speaking, how would you send data from a database and programmatically export it to a custom excel template for a user to download?
I'm getting lost in all of the options out there in 2024 and the different stacks of tech that could be used to accomplish this. A few caveats, a) The original data sits in MySQL. b) The excel template will have custom formatting, fonts, colors. c) Depending on how much data is queried from the database, the excel spreadsheet would have a set number of rows (static number of rows), and could have a dynamic number of columns. N number of rows queried from the database need to be transposed into N number of columns.
For example, the data could be queried from MySQL, be transformed into JSON, sent to a webhook on Microsoft Azure, ingested into Power Automate or Logic Apps, dumped into an excel file, and the file could be sent to a cloud storage bucket like AWS S3.
The stack of technologies I'm looking into at the moment to actually create the excel file:
Specific libraries

PHP and SimpleXLSXGen [https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen]
Python and Pandas Excelwriter [https://pythonbasics.org/write-excel/]
MS Excel native XSD and XML mapping

iPaaS (Integration Platforms as a Service)

Microsoft Power Automate [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/products/power-automate]
Google Cloud Application Integration [https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/all-integration-connectors]
API Spreadsheets [https://www.apispreadsheets.com/]

If I were to use Azure, I am unsure if Power Automate can transpose my data, or can it dump data into a custom template. If I were to use a virtual private server with PHP for SimpleXLSXGen, doesn't that seem overly complicated to build a webhook listener and entire API interface? Seems like there should be a simple solution even if paid in this day and age. Does Microsoft Office 365 and the online version of excel have developer features to import into a custom template?
Thank you for your answer and narrowing down my train of thought.
